# Client Server Chatting in Fedora

Tags: client-server, fedora

I have java program for client and server for chatting. I can run it in windows OS using command prompt and a set of commands. But I want to know how to run this in Fedora?

Comment: Java program is platform independent, you can try to use the same set of commands on Fedora as that on windows. don't forget install JRE on Fedora first via command `sudo yum install java-1.7.0-openjdk`.